# Realtime notification on badge only using ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, websocket

I create realtime notification using ajax by requesting unread notification from database for every 3 seconds,it works well for now,but im not sure it will works well when alot clients connected.

Do i need websocket or still stick with this ajax request?

Comment: Use web socket for better performance.

Comment: @SmitRaval what is your 'better performance' means in spesific?can you explain more details?

Comment: For 100 user, your website will send 100 ajax requests every 3 seconds to your server, now imagine for 1000 users and the load it will put on server. In web socket you can send a new notification when its added to the server and only to the related Users.No need to check every 3 seconds for fetching notifications.

Comment: You can even broadcast message to all 1000 users without putting extreme load on your server.

Comment: @SmitRaval so its depends on how many clients we handle and our purpose right

Comment: Yes. absolutely. Still doing it with AJAX is still not a very good option unless you have very clear idea what you are doing.